# Python, ConfigParser: What is 'magical interpolation'

Tags: python, configparser

The documentation for ConfigParser in Python talks a lot about the so-called "magical interpolation" feature, but never explains what it actually does. I've tried searching for it, but haven't found any answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bad_subj` below would be parsed into `'Notify [failure]'`

```
bad_subj: %(subj)s [failure]
subj: Notify
```

Comment: Okay thanks. What is so 'magical' about that though? Seems like regular variable substitution. Is it the fact that the variable is defined below the place where it is used?

Comment: yeah, I have the same question about this glossary, and I think another a question, when this does feature can used? if all sections and options can wrote in static, e.g.,bad_subj:Notify [failure] directly, maybe it will be used in dynamic assign or substitute. all right??